# Как переписать код под другой стиль

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть пример кода (библиотеки, котоирую я использую).

```
handleInsertButtonClick = (onClick) => {
    console.log('This is my custom function for InserButton click event');
    onClick();
}

createCustomInsertButton = (onClick) => {
    return (
        <InsertButton
            btnText='CustomInsertText'
            btnContextual='btn-warning'
            className='my-custom-class'
            btnGlyphicon='glyphicon-edit'
            onClick={ () => this.handleInsertButtonClick(onClick) }/>
    );
}
//...
const options = {
    insertBtn: this.createCustomInsertButton
};
//...
<BootstrapTable data={rows} options={options} insertRow>
```

Но я использую другой стиль и пытаюсь сделатьт то же под мой стиль. Но выпадает ошибка: Invalid prop `options.insertBtn` of type `object` supplied to `BootstrapTable`, expected `function`.

Пишу так:

```
class TableComponent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.createCustomInsertButton = this.createCustomInsertButton.bind(this);
    this.handleInsertButtonClick = this.handleInsertButtonClick.bind(this);
}

createCustomInsertButton(onClick) {
  return (
      <InsertButton
          btnText='CustomInsertText'
          btnContextual='btn-warning'
          className='my-custom-class'
          btnGlyphicon='glyphicon-edit'
          onClick={ this.handleInsertButtonClick(onClick) }/>
 );
}

render() {
    const options = {
      insertBtn: this.createCustomInsertButton()
    };
.....
```

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: А что за стиль вы используете?

Comment: @RomanC а не знаю как он называется. Но их пример функция не засунуть в мой класс(